# After pushed into array values not in clinch

Tags: angular, typescript

I am pushing some data into the array datax:any = []; but after setInterval the values are not within the clinch.

What the problem here?

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    let datax:any = [1,5];

    console.log(datax);//here the data is within clinch

    setInterval(()=> {
        // let random = Math.round(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
        let test = [1,10, 20, 2, 14];

        for(let x of test){
            datax.push(x);
        }

        console.log(datax); //here the data is not within clinch
    },4000);

    console.log(datax); //here I am getting not data. It is empty but I will need it
}
```

Comment: The problema is that the console.log is executed first than the `setInterval`, put console.log inside the `setInterval`. Also, you may consider to use `concat` to add items from another array :)

Comment: every 4 second push the same data into the same array ? wtf

Comment: It looks not so good. What are you trying to achieve? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ok, I am using a chart and the data expect an array. I want to simulate a realtime chart. For that I need to update the data.